# Can we use Hibernate Cascade without database cascade enabled?

Tags: hibernate, cascade

I want to ask very simple question.

Can we use hibernate's cascade feature without database cascade enabled.

In simple word I have database tables without cascade option ON, but what if put annotation on hibernate & ON cascade true? Will it work or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most if not all hibernates cascading options are handled entirely in code, it should be safe without cascade in db.

Comment: Yes, this really work. I have personally tested. If we just enable Cascade option in our pojos & cascading not enabled at database level, then hibernate cascade work perfectly as required.